# Twenty Eleven theme- have custom landing page, change nav "home" link

Tags: navigation, theme-twenty-eleven

[Live site.](http://growingedgecoaching.com/)

I have a custom landing page on the Twenty Eleven theme. 
Currently, the "Home" nav link is set to the landing page, but I would like to change it to go to /home when clicked on. How do I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you dealing with the navigation menu? . . . .Editing your theme PHP files or configuring WordPress [Navigation Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus)? . . . . Both? . . . . .

Comment: Editing via PHP files.